# Grab form data nested fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cocoon-gem

I have a rails app that used nested fields via the [Cocoon gem](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon):

_form.html.haml:

```
= form_for @project do |f|
   %h3 Tasks
   #tasks
      = f.fields_for :tasks do |task|
          = render 'task_fields', :f => task
      .links
          = link_to_add_association 'add task', f, :tasks
   = f.submit
```

_task_fields.html.haml:

```
.nested-fields
   .field
       = f.label :description
       %br
       = f.text_field :description
       **********HERE's WHERE I WANT TO ECHO OUT THE DESCRIPTION FOR THIS PARTICULAR TASK**
   .field
       = f.check_box :done
       = f.label :done
   = link_to_remove_association "remove task", f
```

What I need to do is retrieve **each** tasks description value on the edit page for the user.

Comment: What do you mean by *retrieve each tasks description value on the edit page for the user*? Don't you already have `task` here? `= f.text_field :description`?

Comment: @User089247, I want to echo out the description again, not in a label or text field. I just want the value of the field.

Comment: what do you mean by echo? You want description to show on page? or it should be shown silently in logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by echo, but to get the `description` of task in **_task_fields.html.haml** you can do this:

```
.nested-fields
   .field
       = f.label :description
       %br
       = f.text_field :description
       = f.object.description # will show description if exists on form's object here.
   .field
       = f.check_box :done
       = f.label :done
   = link_to_remove_association "remove task", f
```